# How external threads on playframework are run

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

we have a service running on `playframework 2.2.6`

there is this thread initiated in the application start (in `onStart` method) that starts the following thread:

```
@Override
public void run(){
  try{
     System.out.println("print my server stats...");
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     Thread t = new Thread(this);
     t.start();
  }catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

this code run smoothly at the beginning (runs abt about every second because of `Thread.sleep(1000)` ) but continously slows down after few hours it does the print out every 5 second or so.

so my questions:

1. how this piece of code is handled in play framework?
2. what happens everything time we call thread.start(), does it use play framework threadPool?
3. is there a way to ensure this piece of code gets enough resources (i.e. does print out every 1 second (ish) )

**NOTE: I appreciate this isn't how a thread should loop but its legacy code and I can't change it**

Also worth noting this piece of code is shared among all other services  and only one of them has this issue (the most used application)

Comment: I don't mind the downvotes, but I greatly appreciate a comment to explain why?

Comment: Hard to understand the system(User's Mind)

Comment: @Deepti I got 5 downvotes while the number of views was 6. I'm in SO for a while, if the question is ambiguous ppl ask for more clarity.

Comment: Yes,I agree with you